# Trying to choose random questions from an array, with answers in a separate array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a program that will ask you random questions from an array. You answer them, and it tells you whether or not you are correct.

I have a questions array:

```
String[] questions = {"Type A", "Type B", "Type C", "Type D", "Type E", "Type F", "Type G"};
```

and then I have an answers array. they correspond with each other, so `answers[0]` is the answer to `questions[0]`

```
 String[] answerKey = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"};
 int questionNum = 0; //Used as a counter for the questions.
```

Here is my code attempt.

```
public void setUpQuestion() {
    String[] answers = new String[4]; //An array of possible answers.
    ArrayList<Integer> usedNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //An Arraylist of question positions.
    ArrayList<Integer> usedQuestions = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //A copy of the usednumbers arraylist


    for (int i = 0; i < answerKey.length; i++) //Add 0 through 6 to this arraylist, represents the questions
        usedNumbers.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(usedNumbers); // Shuffle the arrayList into a random order
    usedQuestions = usedNumbers; //Copy the array

    for (int a = 0; a < answers.length; a++) { // This for loop should add random answers to the answers array
        if (a == 0) {//For the first time around, add the correct answer into the array
            answers[a] = answerKey[usedQuestions.get(questionNum)]; //answers[0] = the correct answer to the question
            usedNumbers.remove(questionNum); //remove it from the copied array, so we don't accidentally use it twice
        } else if (a != 0) { //For the rest of the spots, randomly pick answers that are wrong
                answers[a] = answerKey[usedNumbers.get(0)];//pick a random answer that is next
                usedNumbers.remove(0);//Remove it so it isnt used again

        }
    }
    lblQuestion.setText(questions[usedQuestions.get(questionNum)]); // Set the label to the question
    shuffleArray(answers);//shuffle the array of answers
    btnA.setText(answers[0]); //set the button to one of the answers, etc;
    btnB.setText(answers[1]);
    btnC.setText(answers[2]);
    btnD.setText(answers[3]);

}
```

Hopefully I've commented it thoroughly enough so you know what the code is doing

This seems like it should work in theory, however, when I run it, this happens: 
[image: There is no correct answer listed]
There is no correct answer listed.

If anyone could help me figure out why this isn't working, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

---

Edit:

I have tried a different approach that may work better. I created a Question object that has the parameters of String question, String answer.

So, I made a bunch of new Question objects

```
public int questionNum = 0; //this is a global variable
Question a = new Question("Type A", "A");
Question b = new Question("Type B", "B");
Question c = new Question("Type C", "C");
Question d = new Question("Type D", "D");
Question e = new Question("Type E", "E");
Question[] questionBank = {a, b, c, d, e};
ArrayList<Question> questionArray = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

Here's my new attempt at the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < questionBank.length; i++) questionArray.add(questionBank[i]);//Add all question objects to an arraylist

    String[] answers = new String[4];//possible answers
    Collections.shuffle(questionArray);//randomize thequestion array,

    for (int a = 0; a < answers.length; a++) {
        if (a == 0) {//First time around, add the correct answer to the array
            answers[a] = questionArray.get(questionNum).getA();//getA() method gets the answer from the question array
        } else if (a != 0) {
                answers[a] = questionArray.get(a).getA();
                questionArray.remove(a);
        }
    }

    lblQuestion.setText(questionArray.get(questionNum).getQ()); //Gets the current question
    btnA.setText(answers[0]);
    btnB.setText(answers[1]);
    btnC.setText(answers[2]);
    btnD.setText(answers[3]); //set the answers on the buttons
    questionArray.remove(questionNum);
```

Comment: `shuffleArray(answers)` - care to explain what you're doing here ?

Comment: Why separate the questions from answers into separate arrays to begin with? Why don't you make a `List<QA>` where `QA` contains both questions and answers? There exists `Collections.shuffle()` in the JDK...

Comment: Also, why are questions & answers separated? Encapsulation would suggest you put them together in objects of some new class.

Comment: @alfasin it is just randomly shuffling the array using the Random class.

Comment: @SJuan76 Why not in a `Map` of "<Question, Answer>"?

Comment: @SpencerCarlson and if you shuffle randomly the answers, how do you expect the answers to still be in the same order than the questions???

Comment: @user1803551 you cannot shuffle the entries of a `Map` since a `Map` has no defined order

Comment: @user1803551 that would work better than the current implementation, too, but still opens the door to programming mistakes.

Comment: @fge Why shuffle when you can pick one randomly?

Comment: @SpencerCarlson and when you shuffle the answers - do they still correlate to the questions (i.e. same index...) ?

Comment: @user1803551 because you cannot "pick randomly" from a `Map`, save for selecting a random int from a Random instance, and iterating over the map entries, all the while being careful not to go over the number of entries; no, a `List` and `Collections.shuffle()` it is definitely the best way here

Comment: @SJuan76 the only things I am shuffling are a) An arraylist of numbers. These numbers will be picked as question + answers. The first for loop adds the numbers 0 through 6 into the arraylist, these numbers represent question + answer positions. I'm not actually shuffling the questions and answers, because I need them to be in the same order so I can correctly get the answer.


b) After the for loop, I shuffle the array of possible answers, so it's more random, and so the correct answer isn't always in the 0th position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
usedQuestions = usedNumbers;
```

to

```
usedQuestions = new ArrayList<>(usedNumbers);
```

**How this works**

Observer the following example:

```
Integer h = 3;
Integer j = h;
h++;
System.out.println(j);
```

What will the output be? As you might think, it's `3`.

1. `h` got the value of 3.
2. `j` got the same value as `h`.
3. `h` was changed.
4. `j` wasn't changed.
5. `j` is `h`'s previous value.

Sure enough, you write this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> usedNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> usedQuestions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // add 0, 1, 2
    usedNumbers.add(i);

usedQuestions = usedNumbers;
usedNumbers.remove(0);
System.out.println(usedQuestions);
```

thinking that the output will be `[0, 1, 2]`. Wrong! Let's see the difference from the first case.

1. `usedNumbers` got the values `[0, 1, 2]`.
2. `usedQuestions` got the same value as `usedNumbers`? **NOPE!** `usedQuestions` got the same *reference* as `usedNumbers`. (explanation below)
3. `usedNumbers` was changed.
4. `usedQuestions` *was* changed.
5. `usedQuestions` has the changed value of `[1, 2]`.

In Java, most objects are *reference types*. It means that what the variable it is holding is a reference to the value (a pointer to the address in memory). When you wrote `usedQuestions = usedNumbers` what you did is give the "arrow" which is pointing to the list `[0, 1, 2]` to `usedQuestions`. Now, when you change the list (with `remove`), you change the value of the list, but *every variable which holds a reference to that list will give the same modified list*.

The first example worked as expected because `int` is a *primitive type* where the variable holds a "real" value, and not a pointer to it. In this case changing the number (with `++`) actually changed the value of the number, but all other numbers were remained unchanged.

This goes hand in hand with *shallow copy* vs *deep copy*. There are more questions on this site and articles about it than I'd care to link, so just Google it and you'll get more than what you bargained for. The short explanation is that *shallow copy* only copies the reference which is what you did, while *deep copy* makes a "real" copy of the value. A "real" copy means that

1. Changes to one copy won't affect the other.
2. You are using twice the memory because you are keeping the same data in 2 different addresses.

The line `usedQuestions = new ArrayList<>(usedNumbers);` essentially makes a *deep copy* of the list (only because it's a list of `Integer`), while `usedQuestions = usedNumbers` is a shallow copy.

There are quite a few fine points I didn't address here, nor was I too technically accurate, but I'm trying to explain a subtle and important topic simply.

If you understood this, you might have understood that the line

```
ArrayList<Integer> usedQuestions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

can just be

```
ArrayList<Integer> usedQuestions;
```

The reason is that you don't need to initialize the list at this point in the code as it will be initialized later with `new ArrayList<>(usedNumbers)`. To be specific, in your original code you "threw away" the pointer to the original empty list in the right hand side of

```
ArrayList<Integer> usedQuestions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

when you gave `usedQuestions` the pointer to the list in the right hand side of

```
ArrayList<Integer> usedNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: It shows the correct answers now! Why does that work?

Comment: From testing, it is showing the same questions three or four times. (I made  A - Z) Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: @SpencerCarlson Enjoy! If you can't fix your problem yourself now edit your question with your attempt. However, the second approach with the new class is better.